# widget layout when using interact

Tags: widget, ipython

How can I use a container widget to control the layout while using interact?
For instance, I'd like those 2 Select to be in a HBox.

```
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display

def f(dl, ft):
    print dl, ft

dlW = widgets.Select(options={str(k):k for k in  range(4)})
ftW = widgets.Select(options={str(k):k for k in  'ABCD'})
hbox=widgets.HBox([dlW, ftW])
i = widgets.interact(f,
                 dl = dlW,
                 ft = ftW
                )

# display( hbox ) # <-- commenting in makes the widget display twice
```

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution using interactive instead of interact

```
dlW = widgets.Select(options={str(k):k for k in  range(4)})
ftW = widgets.Select(options={str(k):k for k in  'ABCD'})
i = widgets.interactive(f,
             dl = dlW,
             ft = ftW
            )

hbox=widgets.HBox(i.children)
display( hbox )
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the function is not evaluated until you change your selection.

Comment: The new widget can be made to display immediately by adding the line `hbox.on_displayed(lambda _: f(**i.kwargs))`

Comment: At least for ipywidgets-6.0+, use `i.update()` instead; calling `f` outside of the interactive context will render it to a wrong widget.