# Can I execute widgets.interact() in IPython 3 without displaying extra copies of widgets?

Tags: widget, ipython

Say I have a collection of IPython3 input widgets displayed in an HBox widget. Is there a way to execute widgets.interact() without drawing extra copies of the already-shown input widgets?

Here's an example that illustrates how widgets.interact() draws extra copies of the widgets. Note that if omit the instruction "display(box)", I will see only one copy of each widget, but the widgets will not be contained in the HBox.

I'm running IPython 3.1.0 on Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:32:42) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)].

```
%matplotlib inline

from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myplot(a,b):
    x = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
    y = np.sin(a*x-b)
    plt.plot(x, y)

slider_a = widgets.IntSlider(description='a', min=0, max=10)
slider_b = widgets.IntSlider(description='b', min=0, max=10)
box = widgets.HBox(children=[slider_a, slider_b])

display(box)

widgets.interact(myplot, a=slider_a, b=slider_b)
```

Comment: This workaround also works in your case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332777/widget-layout-when-using-interact